# Getting value in IndexRoute from ApplicationRoute

Tags: ember.js

For some reason I can't get the value of currentUser in the IndexRoute from the ApplicationRoute. If I log it in the ApplicationRoute it has a value, but then if I try to call and log it from the IndexRoute it comes up as undefined. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for the help.

#### ApplicationRoute

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  currentUser: {}
  model: ->
    @store.find('session', 'current').then (session)=>
      @set 'currentUser', session.get('user') if _.isEmpty @get 'currentUser'
      session
```

#### IndexRoute

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition)->
    app = @modelFor 'application'
    console.log app.get 'currentUser'
```

Also tried:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: (->
    app = @modelFor 'application'
    console.log app.get 'currentUser'
  ).on('willTransition')
```

Comment: which code path is it taking? the one where the cookie value exists or doesn't?

Comment: @kingpin2k The one where it doesn't. So if there is a cookie set then it set's the current user. Sorry I should just take that out. It's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**IndexRoute**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor 'application'
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it is a promise issue.  Try returning  @modelFor 'application' instead of assigning it to a value, then accessing it again in the afterModel hook.

You could also try using an intermediary controller instead.

So in your ApplicationRoute just set up an AuthController:

```
this.controllerFor('auth').set('currentUser', this.get('currentUser'));
```

Then see if you can reference that in your other route:

```
this.controllerFor('auth').get('currentUser');
```